# theorem of existence and uniqueness for first order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The theorem of existence and uniqueness is: 
Let $ y'+p(x)y=g(x) $, $ y(x_{0})=y_{0} $ be a first order linear differential equation such that $ p(x) $ and $ g(x) $ are both continuous for $ a<x<b $. Then there is a unique solution that satisfies it.

When a differential equation has no solution that satisfies $ y(x_{0})=y_{0} $, what does this mean?? Can the theorem be verified??

Comment: When you say "When a differential equation has no solution that satisfies $y(x_0)=y_0$", do you mean one that looks like $y'+py=g$?

Comment: The general solution of the differential equation is $y(x)=x(c+\int(s(x))dx)$, $s(x)=\int(\frac{sinx}{x})$ $s(0)=1$and the initial condition is $y(0)=1$. But for no c, the initial value can be verified.

Comment: What differential equation is that?

Comment: $xy'(x)-y(x)=xsin(x)$

Comment: That is not equivalent to $y'(x)-\dfrac{y(x)}x=\sin(x)$, unless you take suitable intervals.

Comment: At my previous post I meant: $ y(x)=x(c+\int(s(x))dx)$, where $s(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{x}$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with 'can the theorem be verified'. Can you rephrase the question, perhaps including the example you're thinking of and explicitly saying what's bothering you?

Comment: I have to show that the fact that there is no solution of the differential equation that satisfies y(0)=1, does not affect the theorem. But how can I show this since one condition of the theorem isn't verified?

Comment: In other words you're asked to prove why the inexistence of solutions to the IVP $xy'(x)-y(x)=x\sin(x), y(0)=1$ does not contradict the theorem. Well, it doesn't because this differential equation doesn't look like $y'+py=q$. Also note that the solutions of $y'(x)-\dfrac{y(x)}x=\sin(x)$ cannot be defined on $x=0$.

Comment: So to show that the inexistence of solutions that satisfy f(0)=1 does not contradict the theorem, I have to say that the solution is not continuous at x=0??

Comment: It's not that it isn't continuous. It doesn't even make sense to talk about continuity because the solutions are not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: So, how can I show this then? I got stuck now.. :/

Comment: If a solution $\varphi$ to $y'(x)-\dfrac{y(x)}x=\sin(x)$ were to be defined at $x=0$, you'd have $\varphi'(0)-\dfrac{\varphi(0)}{\color{red}0}=\sin(0)$ .

Comment: Is the solution f(0)=1 maybe a peculiar solution? And so this doesn't contradict the existence theorem??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existence and uniqueness theorem for first-order linear differential equations can be stated as follows. Suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are continuous on the open interval $I$. If $a$ and $b$ are *any* real numbers, then there is a unique function $y = f(x)$ satisfying the initial-value problem $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$ with $f(a) = b$ on the interval $I$. With regard to your question, the important point is that $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real numbers and the unique solution $f$ to the differential equation satisfies $f(a) = b$ for *every* choice of $a$ and $b$. Since every first-order linear differential equation satisfying the constraints of the theorem has a solution satisfying $f(a) = b$, there is *no* case in which such an equation has no solution satisfying $f(a) = b$.

If we look at the simpler case of homogeneous first-order linear differential equations of the form $y' + P(x)y = 0$, where $P$ is continuous on the open interval $I$, we can directly verify that for every choice of $a$ and $b$, the function $f(x) = be^{-A(x)}$ where $A(x) = \int_{a}^x P(t) dt$ is a solution to $y' + P(x)y = 0$. Now letting $g$ be an arbitrary solution of $y' + P(x)y = 0$, we establish uniqueness by showing that $g(x)e^{A(x)} = b$. Differentiating, we see that $h(x) = g(x)e^{A(x)}$ is constant on the interval $I$. But $h(a) = b$, so we must have $h(x) = b$. This demonstrates that $g = f$. Notice that the choice of $a$ and $b$ does *not* affect the existence or uniqueness of solutions. Can you verify this in the case of non-homogeneous first-order linear differential equations of the form $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$?

Comment: In my case the differential equation is $y'(x)-\frac{1}{x}y(x)=sin(x)$ with $f(0)=1$.
The general solution of this equation is: $ y(x)=x[c+\int{s(x)}dx]$, where $s(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{x}$. For $x=0$ **$y(0)=0$** for any c but **$f(0)=1$**.So there is no solution that satisfies f(0)=1. Am I wrong?

Comment: Since the function $P(x) = -1/x$ is not continuous at $0$, $P$ is not continuous on any open interval containing $0$. This means that there is not necessarily a unique solution of the indicated form to the differential equation. It appears that no solution satisfies f(0) = 1, but this doesn't interfere with the theorem because one of its hypotheses isn't satisfied.

Comment: How could I explain further why this doesn't interfere with the theorem?

Comment: When you transform your differential equation into the form required by the theorem, you violate one of the hypotheses of the theorem - namely, that $P$ be continuous on the relevant interval. Since the $P$ in question isn't continuous on that interval, the theorem doesn't apply. This doesn't mean that there *isn't* a unique solution to the differential equation, just that the existence-uniqueness theorem for first-order linear differential equations won't provide the answer.